# Save Data of LogCat in android

Tags: android

I want to save all the contents of log cat into specific file in Android.
I used Eclipse IDE to develop the android application.

How i can achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a way to get the Logcat contents progrmatically.

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");

 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
     new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

 StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
 String line = "";
 while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
     log.append(line);
 }
```

Check [this](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/16/how-to-read-logcat-contents-programmatically-in-android/) link for more details.

Answer (score 7):

In the logcat tab, select all the lines. Then at the right top, click on the small triangle pointing down, called 'View Menu', and select 'Export Selection as text.."

Answer (score 4):

```
I want to save all the contents of log cat into specific file in Android.
```

LogCat files are stored as circular memory buffers on the device.

If you run "`adb logcat > myfile`" on your host system, you can retrieve the content into a file.

See this : 
https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file

**Other Ways to Extract LogCat:**

1. @Blundell's Way :

   Select the lines of LogCat that you want to save and then simply press Ctrl + C (for copying) and then use Ctrl+V (for paste) in any text file.
2. @Niek's Way :

   In the LogCat tab, select the lines that you want to save. Then at the right top, click on the Small Triangle Pointing Down, called 'View Menu', and select 'Export Selection as text.."
   It will ask you where to save your LogCat file.

Answer (score 0):

Although @Kartik show's you the proper way.

For quickness you can copy and paste.
Ensure the logcat view is open Eclipse > DDMS > logcat

> then click the line you want to start at
>
> hold shift (for multiline select)
>
> click the line you want to finish at
>
> and simply ctrl+c (copy)
>
> ctrl+v (paste whereever you want)

Answer (score 0):

My method allows to get log in testing situation when the device is not connected to ADB

Just create the clone of LogWrapper
and
in constructor create the file in external memory.
I selected DIRECTORY_PICTURES because it is present on all devices.
Constructor
    public LogWrapperExt(){
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("\n hh:mm:ss.SSS");
        String path;
        isValid = true;
        boolean isPresent;
        try {
            topDirPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            if(topDirPath != null )
                path = topDirPath.getCanonicalPath();

```
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        isValid = false;
    } catch (java.lang.NoSuchFieldError e) {
        isValid = false;
    }
    if(isValid){
        logsFolder =   new File(topDirPath + File.separator + "MyLogs");// put your name
        if (!logsFolder.exists()) {
            isPresent = logsFolder.mkdir();
        }
        try {
            String formattedDate = new Date().toString() ;  
            formattedDate = formattedDate.replaceAll(" ", "_");
            String fileName = "test_"+ formattedDate + ".txt";
            logFile = new File(logsFolder.getAbsolutePath(),fileName);
            outputStreamLogFile = new FileOutputStream(logFile);
        } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

then in public void println make your print also.

```
    Log.println(priority, tag, useMsg);

    String myp =  dateStr + " " + level_name[priority] + "  " + tag + " " + useMsg;
    try{
        outputStreamLogFile.write(myp.getBytes());
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {

    }
```

Some overhead - true, but data yours in all situations

Dont forget to replace  LogWrapper name to yours